# Soft delete in SQL Server using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables `tblteam`, `tblaccount` and `tbluser` with the following columns:

`tblTeam`:

```
(TeamId int,
 TeamName varchar(20),
 IsDeleted bit)
```

`tblUser`:

```
(UserId int,
 UserName varchar(20),
 TeamId int)
```

`tblAccount`:

```
(AccountId int,
 AccountName varchar(20),
 TeamId int,
 UserId int
)
```

What I want to do is I want to update the deleted column with 1.

For this I have tried

```
Create procedure sp_isdeleted(
     @pteamid int
As 
Begin
     Update tblTeam 
     set IsDeleted = 1 
     Where TeamId = @pteamid
End
```

But what I want is, if team is associated with any user or account and any user remains in the team `Isdeleted` remains 0.

How can I check this condition? Please help.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_c okay I will use different prefix . Thank you so much for answering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this update statement inside the SP:

```
Update t 
set t.IsDeleted = 1 
from tblTeam t
where t.TeamId = @pteamid 
and not exists (select 1 from tblUser where TeamId = @pteamid)
and not exists (select 1 from tblAcount where TeamId = @pteamid)
```

Comment: if else condition can be applicable here so how cab ne implement if else condition

Comment: I don't understand.. what is the actual question? can you put the questions in other words please?

Comment: I am sorry but still don't understand the question :) What does "bem" means?

Comment: i want to implement if else statement in this stored procedure and then chcek the condition if any user belongs to team A then team A should not be deleted same with Account if any account associated with team A then team A should not be deleted in that case IsDeleted remains 0 otherwise it set IsDeleted 1 to team A

Comment: I think I understand now after detailed information. Thanks. The answer that I wrote actually covers these requirements. Is there a specific reason why you need if else mechanism in this case? Can you check the answer and let me know if that works for you?

Comment: Generally speaking, the IF / ELSE mechanism is available in T-SQL, for other cases there is CASE as well..

Comment: first of all thanku so much its working according to my requirement

Comment: how can implement case or if else if possible

Comment: I would recommend you take a quick tour to Microsoft Books online regarding the IF / ELSE mechanism and also for CASE. It's really easy to understand and use it for your purpose.

Comment: i am trying to learn stored procedure thats why i am struggling , how can i pass an error message of successful update and unsuccessful message .. please help me on this because i want to pass this to the application on based on error message

Answer (score 1):

If you put the logic into one place or many places, there is still the possibility that the soft delete could be performed from some other place. You want to make it impossible to make the deletion from anywhere at any time. Wouldn't it be nice if the system would enforce the default FK restriction (cannot delete a row if there is any FK referring to it) for a soft delete just as it does a hard delete? Say, there's an idea! And it's really quite simple to implement.

Just make the deletion flag part of the PK of the table (or better yet, just add it with the PK to a unique index). Then every FK to Team uses a 0 value in that field. Any attempt to modify the IsDeleted field will be prevented if there is any FK anywhere referring to that Team.

This is from memory so the syntax could be iffy:

```
create table Teams(
    ID        int not null,
    IsDeleted bit not null default 0,
    ...
    constraint PK_Teams primary key( ID )
);
create unique index UQ_Team_ID_IsDeleted on Team( ID, IsDeleted );

create table AllOthers(
    ...
    TeamID         int,
    TeamStillThere bit,
    ...
    constraint CK_TeamStillThere check IsNull( TeamStillThere, 0 ) = 0;
    constraint FK_AllOthers_Teams foreign key( TeamID, TeamStillThere )
        references Teams( ID, IsDeleted );
);
```

Notice that the FK can only refer to an undeleted team and, once a connection is made, the team cannot be deleted( hard or soft). Plus, you can still define FK references to just the PK if that reference doesn't care if the team is deleted or not -- a history of the team, for example. Either way, let the system do all the work wherever possible.